# laravel elixir mapping similar file

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I have many different files which I combined in one file via elixir and gulp.

I also minimize some files which has similar name and different source and also this files storing in the different folders. But in generated `.map-file` I got only unique names of files.

And when I debug my js I got wrong file.
I don't want to rename this files or separate them in the different built files.

Can I create alias for the similar named files?

**UPDATED**:
for example:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var PUBLIC_FOLDER = '../../../public/'

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        PUBLIC_FOLDER + 'js/Controller/Account.js',
        PUBLIC_FOLDER + 'js/Model/Account.js'
   ], 'public/js/app.js' );

    mix.version([
        'public/js/app.js',
    ]);

});
```

It creates app.js.map file:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["Account.js"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;AACA;...."
,"file":"Account.js","sourcesContent":["\....."],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

which contains data only of the first file - "js/Controller/Account.js"

Comment: I think it would make sense to show us your `gulpfile.js`. What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: You're calling it in your blade with `{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}`, right?

Comment: yes, exactly as you are wrote

Comment: Whay are you digging that way to reach your `public` folder? where are your files located?

Comment: Locations of the files: 
`public/js/Controller/Account.js` and `public/js/Model/Account.js`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code doesn't work, anyway I suppose the cause could be your `PUBLIC_FOLDER` variable or where the js files are located.

I have files that shares the same name and have no problem while debugging, that makes your issue particularly weird.

Move your source js files in `resources/assets/js`, that's where Laravel usually put them.

Then edit the `mix.scripts` part of your `gulpfile.js` this way

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/Controller/Account.js',
    'resources/assets/js/Model/Account.js'
], 'public/js/app.js', './');
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said but I got the same problem. Also I installed laravel 5.3 - the same.
My app.js.map file:
`{"version":3,"sources":["Account.js"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;AAAA","file":"app.js","sourcesContent":["alert(2)"],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}`. 
As you see it contains data only second file `Model/Account.js`. It makes difficult to debug

Comment: What if you symlink one of them? Consider it to be an alias like `ControllerAccount`, you would edit the same file without touching too much the directory structure, but it would be recognised by elixir as a different file.

Comment: Yes it is good solution, but I don't want change all files in the project. I thought elixir has something like alias. But anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: I have the same problem too, have 2 folders: `x/controller.js` and `y/controller.js` and when build I see only the last file `y/controller.js` but not working the javascript ... any1 ideea when can be fixed this on laravel-elixir ?

Comment: @Laurentiu I'm not sure there will be any new feature, new improvements are focused on Laravel Mix https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix